# How to sort a object in python with the key that are provided during run time?

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.6

Let's say there is User object having field 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age' and so on.

I know that I need to sort according to one of the above mention property but I will only know the exact property at run time.

The thing I have tried

```
def sortBySomeSpecificKey(key_name):    
         #key_name is given to the function 
         Users = sorted(Users, key=lambda x: x.key_name, reverse=True)
```

The problem with this approach is, Instead of taking value of *key_name*, it is taking key_name as the property itself.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
Users = sorted(Users, key=lambda x: getattr(x, key_name), reverse=True)
```

Another option is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) instead of lambda

```
from functools import partial
key = partial(gettatr, name=key_name)
Users = sorted(Users, key=key, reverse=True)
```

As a side note - better add argument to pass the collection instead of using global variable and return from your function.